'Lambda' object has no attribute 'filter_log_events'
Receiving the following error when I try to iterate through all my lambdas to get the last execution/invocation date and time.
'Lambda' object has no attribute 'filter_log_events'
def get_last_run_time(function_name):
    client = boto3.client('lambda')

    try:
        log_group = f"/aws/lambda/{function_name}"
        log_response = client.filter_log_events(logGroupName=log_group, orderBy='timestamp', descending=True, limit=1)
        if log_response['events']:
            last_invocation_time = log_response['events'][0]['timestamp']
        else:
            last_invocation_time = "No recent invocations"
        return last_modified
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting last run time for {function_name}: {e}")
        return e


What "following error"? Please post the full error with its traceback.

The Lambda client has no such function.  Your code appears to be reading CloudWatch logs, so you want to use client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

The error occurs because the filter_log_events method is not available in the boto3.client('lambda') object. The filter_log_events method is part of the CloudWatch Logs API.
You should use the boto3.client('logs') to interact with CloudWatch Logs and filter events from the log group associated with the Lambda function, somthing like this :
import boto3

def get_last_run_time(function_name):
    logs_client = boto3.client('logs') 
    log_group = f"/aws/lambda/{function_name}"

    try:
        log_response = logs_client.filter_log_events(
            logGroupName=log_group,
            limit=1,  
            startTime=0,  
            interleaved=True, 
            orderBy='LogStreamName', 
        )

        if log_response['events']:
            last_invocation_time = log_response['events'][0]['timestamp']
            return last_invocation_time
        else:
            return "No recent invocations"

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting last run time for {function_name}: {e}")
        return str(e)

